# Banning users from Facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to ban users from using a Facebook application?
I'm not talking about the canvas or the discussions board (which is what I've found by looking around), but the application itself, that is, causing errors or preventing actions whenever the user tries to use the Graph API (in my specific case, an Android app that uses the Graph API to provide some features).

The scenario I'm envisaging is something like this:

1. user authenticates app to use its features and gets the access_token;
2. user uses the Graph API according to the app permissions;
3. user someday does something he shouldn't;
4. user is banned and, even if the access_token is still valid, Graph API requests fail, and will always fail even when deauthorizing and authorizing the app again.

Is this possible using the Graph API or the developers app console on Facebook, right now, or is there really no way to prevent users from misusing your application? I guess I may do something "out of band" to enforce this somehow, but being able to do it at the Facebook level as well would be much more effective and harder to circumvent.

Answer (score 2):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Use the 'banned' connection of the Application object to ban specific users from your App - you'll need the [App access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/authentication#applogin) to do this

Comment: I've just played a bit with the banned connection but, while I formally seem to be able to ban and unban correctly a user (checking the connection shows the user there), the user is still able to make API calls using the access_token and get correct responses, which is what I'm trying to prevent instead... or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Huh, that doesn't match my understanding of how that's supposed to work, let me take a look at the backend code, could be a bug

Comment: (side note: Making a HTTP DELETE to /[USER]/permissions using that user's access token or the app access token will uninstall the app from their account, but probably doesn't prevent them reauthenticating later)

Comment: OK it seems to only block canvas accesses, not the API overall - if uninstalling the app forcibly isn't enough I think you'll need to file a bug report / wishlist task (not sure if it's supposed to work any differently) about the fact that a banned user's access tokens aren't invalidated and they can still auth the app

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for the side note as well which I was not aware of! even though, as you noticed, it wouldn't be of much help anyway. I'll file the bug report since IMHO that's how banning an application should behave.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a blacklist of specific Facebook User IDs, and check the user's ID against the blacklist when they log into your app.

If the blacklist matches, show a message telling them that they are banned and don't allow access to any functionality.

Comment: While this is technically valid - @Igy has detailed a method that is dealt with by Facebook.  IMO, for this case it would be preferable to use an already existing system.

Comment: The problem is my app is not a canvas app. I have an Android app which sends Graph API requests directly, and handles responses by itself. I've tried the banned connection as suggested below but to no avail so far.